# Implementing TDLeaf algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am implementing a game playing agent which uses the minimax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning and early cutoff. My minimax algorithm cuts off at a depth of 8, and uses an evaluation function which approximates the utility value. I have hard-coded this utility function.

I would like to use the TDLeaf algorithm to alter the constants of this utility function however I am not sure which option to take: 
1. Apply the TDLeaf algorithm while playing against a good opponent and hardcode the resulting utility function. 
2. Keep my current hardcoded utility function and apply TDLeaf algorithm for each opponent I play and learn the constants dynamically (is this bad because agent is always learning)?
3. Follow another strategy?